# Build .NET 2.0 project with 4.0 dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

In order to create a C# CLR function, I need to create an assembly of my dll on a SQL Server 2008 SP3 machine. I have to build my project targeting .NET 2.0 as it appears that SQL Server 2008 only works with version 2.0. The problem is that my project has references to the other projects in the same solution which are all in version 4.0 and I cannot change them.

I did some searching online and it seems like you could create an application that targets the .NET Framework 4 referencing assemblies that targets .NET Framework 2.0 but not the other way around. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx)

Is there a workaround of this? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No way around. You'll have to downgrade all other projects to either 2.0 or upgrade current project to .net 4.0.

Comment: You could build a separate wcf service for db access that runs on 2.0 that is called by the 4.0 App.

Comment: SQLCLR in SQL Server 2012 and later hosts .NET 4.0 if a database server upgrade is an option.

Comment: Looks like the "workaround" will be something outside CLR function. Thank you all for your help.